# My Flutter app already runs in Chrome so why add web support?

Tags: flutter

I created a Flutter app a few years ago (before web support was an option) and have always just targeted iOS and Android. Now I want to target web as well. The project did not have a `web` directory, only an `ios` and `android` directory, but if I selected Chrome as the run target then the app would build and run in Chrome fine with no problems.

The [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/building#add-web-support-to-an-existing-app) says that to add web support to an existing project, I should run the command `flutter create --platforms web .` so I ran this command and a `web` directory containing an index.html file, a `manifest.json` file and a bunch of icons was added to my project.

The only change I've noticed when running my app in Chrome since running the above command is that a favicon now appears in the Chrome tab.

So my question is why is it necessary to run the above command and "add web support" to a Flutter project if it already ran fine in Chrome before running the above command? What other benefits does this command provide, apart from displaying a favicon?

Comment: Since asking this question, I've noticed that even though you can run a Flutter app that doesn't have web support in Chrome locally, when it comes to actually building the web app for release (using `flutter build web`), the Flutter CLI errors and says 'Missing index.html.' So I guess that's a pretty good reason to add web support to a Flutter project and kind of answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the web/ folder for all your web related things. For example, I have my webworker things there because only in web you cannot use isolates. You can also use this web/ folder to run your project on web not just on your local environment. The quote continues with "created using a previous version of Flutter". So I would assume that this was requirement for older version but I am not sure how the building and running for web works. You can run the project in chrome without web/ folder. This adds a build into the build/ folder.